# Simple Powershell Script to restart network adapter becomes unsimple to make work on restricted user accounts

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-8.1

So all I want to do is create a shortcut script that when clicked will *restart the network adapter*. The issue is that it needs to be ran on an account with basically no privileges so I need to have it run elevated and as a different user (admin account).

I cant quite figure out the right way to do this and its driving me nuts. This is what I have so far:

```
$username = "Domain\User"
$password = "Password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
start-process powershell -Credential ($credentials) -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -noprofile -verb runas -inputformat text -command "{restart-netadapter -InterfaceDescription "Dell Wireless 1538 802.11 a/g/n Adapter" -Confirm:$false}"'
```

It will open a new powershell window but the command fails to run. It works fine on its own in an elevated powershell prompt. I found out at one point that even though I was calling the powershell using an admin account it wasn't an elevated powershell so I added the `-verb runas` but it still isn't working.

This really shouldn't be that hard, but I am not a powershell guru by any means. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well first thing I notice is that you have Passwords in Plain text which is not ideal, and I will tell you that trying to secure that password if no easy task. I will see if I can find the code I used to launch the Admin Powershell and I will get back to you though

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to create a scheduled task that runs the script as a privileged account. Get rid of the embedded credentials altogether.

The limited account then only needs to be able to start the task.

Since the code to restart the adapter is a one-liner, you don't need even need to put it in a script file, so you don't need to worry about execution policy or anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used to get mine to work, I can't take credit for writing it because I found it from [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script.aspx)

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object     System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
  {
   # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background     color to indicate this
   $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
   $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
   clear-host
   }
else
   {
   # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator

   # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
   $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

# Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
$newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

# Indicate that the process should be elevated
$newProcess.Verb = "runas";

# Start the new process
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

# Exit from the current, unelevated, process
exit
}

# Run your code that needs to be elevated here
Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

But this checks to see if it is elevated and then elevates it if it isn't.

Comment: Its not going to elevate it though without asking for credentials. I can get it to start using
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file C:\wifi_reset.ps1' -verb RunAs
However it will ask for credentials on the other account in order to elevate it.
If I add -Credential to start-process it doesn't want to do it with the -verb RunAs at the end.

Comment: Right you will need to change the code for you needs, this worked for me but you can hard code the credentials into this and it should do what you need it to.